# how to make perfect circle without using px in lenth & width

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to create a circle using css , without using svg circle and i don't want to use px in length and width cos i want my project lill responsive for all devices, i want to use %...

here is im using

```
circle{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15%;
  height: 25%; 
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #dfdfdf;

<box class="circle"></box>
```

//is their any script or method to find out height width ratio for every device and make circle perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using % to make a circle responsive :

```
<div class="circle"></div>

.circle {
    width: 50%;
    height:0;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #4679BD;
}
```

In addition, here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4f20np2/).

In this case, the padding-bottom attribute takes 50% of the parent div. If you want to reduce the size, you can place it inside another container.

In addition, % defined within a padding in CSS, are calculated based on the width of the container. This means that if you use a padding-bottom to the circle that equals the width `width: 50%` && `padding-bottom: 50%`, it will give the element the same height as its width.

Comment: Pretty cool, can you explain how it works? How to change the dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewport units in modern browsers.

Support - [**CanIUse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

MDN Link - [**Viewport Units**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #dfdfdf;
}
.width {
  width: 15vw;
  height: 15vw;
}
.height {
  width: 15vh;
  height: 15vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle height"></div>


<div class="circle width"></div>
```